# Form submit with one email for multi step

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

Im looking for some guidance on a small issue.

I created a php/html/css form and included a javascript step by step process. When step 1 is completed the info is sent to my email just incase the user exits the form after step one. Then once step 2 and 3 are completed I get another email that contains everything from step 1-3 after the submit button is submitted.

However I would like to make this into one email being sent even if the user exits after step 1. What are my options?

**Edit:**
**Can I somehow delay the sending of the first email and only send it if the second step is aborted by abandoning the page.**

Comment: Store it in a database at each step.

Email once complete.

Comment: You can use sessionStorage to store the data. Get in some token to confirm the user.